# Multi-line equation groups with one number

Tags: numbering, align

I would like to number a multi-line multi-column equation group with one number. If I use

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    x&=1 & x&=2\\
    y&=3 & y&=4
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I get an equation number per row. When using the `split` environment

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        x&=1 & x&=2\\
        y&=3 & y&=4
    \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

the groups are omitted and I have one number for four rows.

How can I number the first example with one number?

**Edit:**

I used the `equation` and `aligned` environments proposed by @daleif and got the following results in equation (3). Equation (1) and (2) are typeset by an `align` environment:

[image: <code>align</code> vs. <code>aligned</code>]

The `align` environment uses the whole width of the document. Is this possible with `aligned`, too?

Comment: Use `aligned` inside `equation`.

Comment: Follow @Sigur's advice, and **please** never use `split` inside `align`!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What's wrong with `split` inside `align`? Though I tend to go for `equation` plus `aligned`

Comment: If it works.... However I'd not even use `split` in any case, see the example in my answer.

Comment: @daleif While `align` is meant to be a standalone environment, `split` and `aligned` are meant to be used inside `equation`

Comment: @karlkoeller aligned are perfectly suited to go inside `align`, I use it quite often within `align*`, when soemthing is broken across lines within pairs of braces.

Comment: @daleif I was probably wrong, because the last example in your answer shows that it can be needed. :-)

Comment: @karlkoeller, no problem. Looking at the sources, it seems intentional. The code does check to see if it is inside `align` or not.

Comment: @All I marked to reopen this question, because my problem is to number a multi-line multi-column equation with one number. The recommend thread handles a multi equation with only one column.

Answer (score 7):

I'd actually go for `equation` plus `aligned` as that combination still have `equations` space saving feature, whereas `equation` plus `split` does not.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent sd\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    a\\ b
  \end{split}
\end{equation}


\noindent sd\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    a\\ b
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

See the spacing below the special line

[image]

On a side note, `aligned` also has its uses inside `align*` (does not work well with numbered lines then using the `[t]` or `[b]` optional arg)

```
\begin{align*}
  f(x) = {} &  \sum \dots \\
  & + \sum_i
  \!
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    \Bigl[ &a_i +b_i+\cdots
    \\ & + x_i+y_i\Bigr]
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please add two columns to this example and you will see, that the `split` environment omits these columns. In addition, the `aligned` environment does not use the whole width like the `align` environment does. Is this possible? (I make a note in my initial post.)

Comment: @Dirk `split` only supports *one* alignment column (ie one `&`) per row. If you need more, use `aligned`. What do you mean by using the whole width?

Comment: I add an example to my initial post. Does this clarify my question?

Comment: @Dirk, it that case you can use `alignedat` instead, and then manually set the space between cols. `aligned` use a minimalist approach. Looking at the sources, one might also be able to use, say, `\renewcommand{\minalignsep}{5em}` however I do not know what other effect messing with this might have. The default value is `10pt`.

Comment: Remember that `align` does a lot of measuring and readjustments, `aligned` does not, it is a much simpler construction.